# What method is most preferred to find nature of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{a^n+x^n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I tried to use D'Alembert's ratio test to test the convergence of the given series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{a^n}{a^n+x^n}$ but I could only solve for $\frac{a}{x} <1$ and it is coming out to be converging but for $\frac{x}{a} <1$, I am not able to do it with ratio test.

Comment: What do u mean by $\frac(|xa|)<1$

Comment: I was trying to add fraction. But failed. I will edit it now

Comment: Edited now. Thank you for help.

Comment: Very simply: what is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}{a^n+x^n}$ if $x\lt a$? What properties do a series' terms need for that series to converge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{a^n}{a^n + x^n} = \frac{1}{1 + (\frac{x}{a})^n}$$
Ratio test:
$$\frac{\frac{a^{n+1}}{a^{n+1} + x^{n+1}}}{\frac{a^n}{a^n + x^n}} = a \frac{a^n + x^n}{a^{n+1} + x^{n+1}} =  \frac{1 + (\frac{x}{a})^n}{1 + (\frac{x}{a})^{n+1}}$$

- If $\vert \frac{x}{a} \vert \leq 1$, the above limits goes to $1$. And the ratio test here is inconclusive. Note here that $\frac{a^n}{a^n + x^n} = \frac{1}{1 + (\frac{x}{a})^n}$ does not go to zero (goes to $1$). The series diverges. This test is referred to as $n^{th}$ term test.
- If $\vert \frac{x}{a} \vert > 1$, the above limit acts as 
  $$\frac{(\frac{x}{a})^n}{(\frac{x}{a})^{n+1}} = \frac{a}{x} < 1$$

Thanks @DanielWainfleet for the remark on absolute values.

Comment: So it failed for $\frac{x}{a}$ <1 because the value is 1, right? Okay, understood. Thank you

Comment: Yes but we did not use ratio test. We used $n^{th}$ term test when $\frac{x}{a} \leq 1$, i.e. $\sum b_n$ diverges if $b_n$ converges to a non-zero quantity.

Comment: Yes, I forgot nth term test. Got it.

Comment: I don't see it stated that $a,x$ are necessarily non-negative. If $x/a=-2$ the series converges. Better to consider the value of $|x/a|$ or $|a/x|$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet i have re-edited .. thank you for the comment.

Comment: Looks fine now........+1